# Using a prepared mysql statement in a php for loop?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm using a prepared statement and a for loop to insert multiple products into a table.. the problem I'm having is it only inputs the first product from the form. I have the echo statements to test if the for loop is working and all the correct values are echo'd out on my page. Why won't it insert more than the first product into my table?

```
<?php
session_start();

//db info

$conn = new mysqli("$server","$user_name","$password","$database");

$productName = $_POST['productName'];
$productPrice = $_POST['productPrice'];
$productDescription = $_POST['productDescription'];
$productImage = $_POST['productImage'];
$id = $_SESSION['id'];



if (isset($productName) && isset($productPrice) && isset($productDescription) && isset($productImage)) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Products (id, productNumber, productName, productPrice, productDescription, productImage) 
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("iissss", $id, $productNumber, $productNames, $productPrices, $productDescriptions, $productImages);

    $productNameCount = count($productName);

    for($i = 0; $i < $productNameCount; $i++) {
        $productNumber = $i + 1;
        echo $id." ";
        echo $productNumber." ";
        $productNames = $productName[$i];
        echo $productNames." ";
        $productPrices = $productPrice[$i];
        echo $productPrices." ";
        $productDescriptions = $productDescription[$i];
        echo $productDescriptions." ";
        $productImages = $productImage[$i];
        echo $productImages."<br>";
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->reset();
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: and if you comment out the `$stmt->reset()`?

Comment: That didn't change anything.

Comment: @JRD No you don't. It binds to references, so changes to the variables should work.

Comment: Check for errors from `$stmt->execute()`. My guess is you have duplicate IDs.

Comment: Is `id` supposed to be a unique key? You're sending `$_SESSION['id']` for every insert.

Comment: If `id` is an `auto_increment` key, you should just leave it out of the insert, and the database will automatically increment it.

Comment: @Barmar Shows how much I know, ok you only have to bind once.